# How to sync Outlook photo/contact to SharePoint page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

**Goal:** Sync Outlook photo, name, and job title to SharePoint page/site.

**Current process:** 
We currently have a SharePoint page (photo gallery) that has employee photos, name, and title. Not all of our employees are on this page, but the goal is to change that. The difference between the purpose of Outlook contact photo and the SharePoint contact photo is being able to scroll through employee's photos if you do not know the name of one. Outlook contact photos help if you know the name, but not the face. We are currently uploading photos to two different places, and not all employees exist on the SharePoint site.

Is there a way to achieve the goal of syncing Outlook photo/name/title to a SharePoint gallery (or other type of page)?

**Tech Info:** Office 365/Outlook 2013, SharePoint 2013